# I have a local SQL Server Data base. It's working in local. I am trying to pass from Local database to Azure.It's not working using .net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have a local SQL Server Data base. It's working in local.  I am trying to pass from Local database to Azure and it is not working.

My local connection code is as follows:

```
add name="TestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Here is the Azure connection code that is not working:

```
add name="TestConnectionString"  connectionString="Server=tcp:.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testdb; Connection Timeout=30; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=False;"
```

How can I  solve this connection problem?

Comment: you forgot to post some code.

Comment: Where is your code man?

Comment: Thanks for your response...

Comment: Can you please post the error message that you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SQL Express once you deploy to Azure.

The data storage possibilities for your application running in Azure Web Sites are: Azure SQL Database, Azure Blob Storage, Azure Table Storage, MySQL database ...

If you want you can use SQL Compact edition on azure id you don't want to pay for SQL Azure:
You can install: SqlServerCompact nuget package.

Your SQL Compact Edition connection string will look like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TwoNotes.mdf" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Here is an article on how to do that:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/883/host-aspnet-mvc-azure-without-database

Comment: @user2369568 no problem, did that answer the question? maybe you can mark it as answer if yes.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

The connection string needs to be modified to the Azure SQL DB, since Express and SQLDB are different backends.

An Azure SQL DB connection string should look like this:

```
Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=testDB;User ID=MyAdmin@xxxxxxxxxx;Password=pass@word1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

You can obtain this connection string from the Azure Portal. This article contains additional information on how to create a database and connect to it from ASP.NET: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-dotnet-how-to-use/

Luis